# Using grep and sed to find and replace a string

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sed, grep

I am using the following to search a directory recursively for specific string and replace it with another:

```
grep -rl oldstr path | xargs sed -i 's/oldstr/newstr/g'
```

This works okay. The only problem is that if the string doesn't exist then `sed` fails because it doesn't get any arguments. This is a problem for me since i'm running this automatically with ANT and the build fails since `sed` fails.

Is there a way to make it fail-proof in case the string is not found?

I'm interested in a one line simple solution I can use (not necessarily with `grep` or `sed` but with common unix commands like these).

Comment: the reason i want to keep it as simple as possible is because my script connects to a remote server and runs this line with SSH. if i would use a shell script for this, i would have to copy the shell  script to the server before and then run it there. i'm trying to avoid it and keep it simple. thanks.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/257250/how-to-run-sed-on-over-10-million-files-in-a-directory

Comment: Coming here from Google, I was looking for the exact string given in the question! (I didn't have the problem the OP was suffering from)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can use `find` and `-exec` directly into `sed` rather than first locating `oldstr` with `grep`.  It's maybe a bit less efficient, but that might not be important.  This way, the `sed` replacement is executed over all files listed by `find`, but if `oldstr` isn't there it obviously won't operate on it.

```
find /path -type f -exec sed -i 's/oldstr/newstr/g' {} \;
```

Comment: @Vlad: It is, because you're running a separate `sed` for each file instead of letting `xargs` batch them. That said, unless you're talking about several thousand tiny files, you're unlikely to notice a difference.

Comment: @geekosaur: Oh, right.. I haven't thought about a number of execs shell should make. Good point!

Comment: thanks, i tried your solution. it did solve my return value problem, now it returns 0 when it doesn't find anything. the problem is that it returns : `sed: no input files` even though i have files with the oldstring in the directory. know why ?

Comment: i'm using this in directory tree with possibly thousand of files to look in (although the amount of files that actually need change is not big) is that an issue ?

Comment: My problem with this: the timestamp of every file will get reset to "right now" as if they were all "touched", even if no edits occurred in the file.

Comment: I've seen this "Hello world" example of using find all over the place, but nothing that constrains it from running sed on every file, including binaries.  I have yet to find a working example with pipes, and I've tried a number of ways to hack the simplistic version of very limited utility.

Comment: @JerryMiller you can of course limit `find` to specific filename patterns, which is what I often do:  `find -name "*.c" -o -name "*.h" -type f -exec sed...` would modify all the .c and .h files for example...  To exclude binary files, it can get more complicated: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46276/finding-all-non-binary-files

Comment: But if you want a solution with `grep` and `sed` : `find . -name "find_files" -exec grep -l "text_to_find" {} \; -exec sed -i 's/change_text/to_this_text/g' {} \;`   The `grep` `-l` option returns a list of files, instead of the text found.

Comment: Worked for me. Made me save quite much time. Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

Your solution is ok. only try it in this way:

```
files=$(grep -rl oldstr path) && echo $files | xargs sed....
```

so execute the `xargs` only when grep return `0`, e.g. when found the string in some files.

Comment: That is a nice underestimated solution! This is what I needed to execute sed over a list of files output of grep, and avoid the error: "can't read .... No such file or directory". Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Agree with @Leopoldo. This looks like the most Posixy and portable (for OS like Solaris) and the one with the least side effects (not touching every file mtime, etc). `files=$(grep -rl oldstr path | cut -f 1 -d ':' | sort | uniq)` should build a smaller list where the files are listed once.

Answer (score 9):

I have taken Vlad's idea and changed it a little bit. Instead of

```
grep -rl oldstr path | xargs sed -i 's/oldstr/newstr/g' /dev/null
```

Which yields

```
sed: couldn't edit /dev/null: not a regular file
```

I'm doing in 3 different connections to the remote server

```
touch deleteme
grep -rl oldstr path | xargs sed -i 's/oldstr/newstr/g' ./deleteme
rm deleteme
```

Although this is less elegant and requires 2 more connections to the server (maybe there's a way to do it all in one line) it does the job efficiently as well

Comment: And this script save my life!

Answer (score 8):

Standard `xargs` has no good way to do it; you're better off using `find -exec` as someone else suggested, or wrap the `sed` in a script which does nothing if there are no arguments.  GNU `xargs` has the `--no-run-if-empty` option, and BSD / OS X `xargs` has the `-L` option which looks like it should do something similar.

Comment: thanks, i tried to use --no-run-if-empty but it still returns nonzero code (returns 1) and that would also trigger a build fail for me. how generic and common is `find` command ?

Comment: `find -exec` goes back to 7th Research Edition UNIX; it should work anywhere that has `find` installed.

Comment: +1 I'm surprised the `xargs -r` fix is not mentioned in more answers.  For this limited use case, it's simple and sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

I think that without using `-exec` you can simply provide `/dev/null` as at least one argument in case nothing is found:

```
grep -rl oldstr path | xargs sed -i 's/oldstr/newstr/g' /dev/null
```

Comment: could be a very neat workaround. sadly i get `sed: couldn't edit /dev/null: not a regular file` :)

Comment: @michael: Turns out - running anything like this will actually crash the shell because of too many arguments... See http://superuser.com/questions/257250/how-to-run-sed-on-over-10-million-files-in-a-directory

Comment: there are a lot of files in my directory but only few of them contain the string i want to change. so i am not so worried about too many arguments to sed.

Comment: @michael: The solution listed there with 10 votes should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

My use case was I wanted to replace 
`foo:/Drive_Letter` with `foo:/bar/baz/xyz`
In my case I was able to do it with the following code.
I was in the same directory location where there were bulk of files.

```
find . -name "*.library" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '' -e 's/foo:\/Drive_Letter:/foo:\/bar\/baz\/xyz/g'
```

hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will be helpful but you can use this with a remote server like the example below

ssh example.server.com "find /DIR_NAME -type f -name "FILES_LOOKING_FOR" -exec sed -i 's/LOOKINGFOR/withThisString/g' {} ;"

replace the example.server.com with your server
replace DIR_NAME with your directory/file locations
replace FILES_LOOKING_FOR with files you are looking for
replace LOOKINGFOR with what you are looking for
replace withThisString with what your want to be replaced in the file

Answer (score -1):

If you are to replace a fixed string or some pattern, I would also like to add the bash builtin pattern string replacement variable substitution construct. Instead of describing it myself, I am quoting the section from the bash manual:

> `${parameter/pattern/string}`
>
> The pattern is expanded to produce a pattern just as in pathname
>                 expansion.   *parameter* is expanded and the longest match of *pattern* against its value is replaced  with  *string*.   If  *pattern*
>                 begins  with `/`, all matches of *pattern* are replaced with string.
>                 Normally only the first match is replaced.   If  *pattern*  begins
>                 with  `#`, it must match at the beginning of the expanded value of
>                 *parameter*.  If *pattern* begins with `%`, it must match at  the  end
>                 of  the expanded value of *parameter*.  If *string* is null, matches
>                 of *pattern* are deleted and the `/` following *pattern* may be  omitted.   If  *parameter*  is  `@`  or `*`, the substitution operation is
>                 applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the  expansion
>                 is  the  resultant list.  If *parameter* is an array variable subscripted with `@` or `*`, the substitution operation is  applied  to
>                 each  member  of  the  array  in  turn, and the expansion is the
>                 resultant list.