# non ascii special char remove from csv file

Tags: linux, shell, awk

While i am editing csv file in linux special character look like Â£stackoverflow, Â£unixbox,Â£query. My query is how to remove Â from csv file.

Input: Â£stackoverflow, Â£unixbox,Â£query
Output: £stackoverflow, £unixbox,£query

Observations of linux box:
currently linux window translation setting is ISO-8859-1, while i am changing the window setting--->translation-->UTF-8 then open the same file using vi editior  Â char being disappeared.I have tried iconv command as well but didn't work.It may be the reason that i am conv the file ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 but by default setting of linux is ISO-8859-1 so it is showing me Â it is not removing this char.How to handle it to remove the same.

Comment: `sed 's/Â//g' file`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using grep and sed to find and replace a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6178498/608639)

Comment: I think you should circle back to fix what's actually wrong. What are the original bytes and which character encoding was used to write them?

Comment: thank you, but i am not able to copy Â char in linux box while i am copying space or reversing the other char, so it is not helpful as of now

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below Perl solution. This removes all the ordinal values that are not in the range of 32 to 127 (which contains the ascii text)

```
$ echo "Â£stackoverflow, Â£unixbox,Â£query Output: £stackoverflow, £unixbox,£query" | perl -pe ' s/[^\x20-\x7f]//g '
stackoverflow, unixbox,query Output: stackoverflow, unixbox,query
$
```

EDIT:

To remove just Â, use

```
$ echo "Â" | perl -pe ' s/./sprintf("%x |",ord($&))/eg '  # Find the underlying ordinal values for Â 
c3 |82 |

$ echo "Â£stackoverflow, Â£unixbox,Â£query" | perl -pe ' s/\xc3\x82//g ' #removing it using s///
£stackoverflow, £unixbox,£query

$
```

Comment: thanks for help, but my ask was, input: Â£stackoverflow, Â£unixbox,Â£query and result would be £stackoverflow, £unixbox,£query

Comment: it didn't work in my case because i am not able to read Â£ in linux only in vi editor i can see this otherwise it look like £ only. but  my asked is even after vi editor it should look like actual value £  instead of Â£. and also if you can share synatx to convert $ to £ inside file in linux.currently linux is not able to read £ char

Comment: it might be some other character.. can you collect the hexdump of the file

Comment: ````hexdump <filename>````

Comment: ````echo "$" | sed 's/\$/£/g'````

Comment: thanks mate but i am not able to copy pound sign in linux box. sed command not able to used.

Comment: £ sign octal code is 243 and speical char is looks like Â£. octal codde for Â (302)and £(243).Issue here is not able to copy Â char in linuxbox it paste as a space and revesing the words. e.g: if in linux using vi editor it looks "stack Â£overflow", when i will copy and paste in linux terminal then it will look "overflow 
     stack ".how to handle it