# Searching and replacing specific string within files on all directories

Tags: linux, unix, sed, replace, grep

This question is related to
[How to search and replace using grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15402770/how-to-search-and-replace-using-grep)
[Using grep and sed to find and replace a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178498/using-grep-and-sed-to-find-and-replace-a-string)

However, these were ambiguous as to if they searched for the string inside the files, or just their file names.

I would like to be able to search all files on the system (searching from the root directory, going into all subdirectories) for a specific string inside them (it's specifically an IP Address), and change it for another string (another IP Address), regardless of files names.

Thanks in advance

I've tried

```
find /path -type f -exec sed -i 's/oldstr/newstr/g' {} \;
```

Also

```
sed -i 's/\(.*\)substring\(.*\)/\1replace\2/'
```

Comment: `sed` replaces inside the files.

Comment: Your first command should do it. You can improve performance by using `+` instead of `\;` since it won't start a new `sed` for each file.

Comment: What Barmar said ... the find **should** do the job if the `oldstr` is correct.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I do a recursive find/replace of a string with awk or sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583219/how-can-i-do-a-recursive-find-replace-of-a-string-with-awk-or-sed)

Comment: `grep -r -F -I -l -Z -e 'oldstr' / 2>/dev/null | xargs -0 sed -e 's/oldstr/newstr/gp'` might also work.